# How can i set the subscription in Azure using Set-AzContext in Jenkins?

Tags: powershell, jenkins

I have a freestyle job in Jenkins with a powershell build step as follows:

```
az account clear
$pwd1 = "testpwd"
$uname = "testuser"
az login -u "$uname" -p "$pwd1"
Set-AzContext -SubscriptionId <subscription-id>
...
```

But i get the error:

```
Set-AzContext : The term 'Set-AzContext' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable
```

Any ideas as to why this would be happening , or how i can fix this ?

Answer (score 1):

It looks like the `Az` module is not available. Run the below command:

```
Get-Module -Name Az -All
```

If `Set-AzContext` is missing, or if nothing gets listed at all, you need to install the Az module. To do that, refer to the [official documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/azure/install-az-ps?view=azps-9.0.0&viewFallbackFrom=azps-6.6.0).

Comment: I am running powershell script in Jenkins. The version of Jenkins is 1.7 , so does that mean i need to install the module on the machine running Jenkins ?

Comment: @Tracey Yes it needs to be on the machine itself